# How to show that filter convergence implies Hausdorff

Tags: general-topology, convergence-divergence, filters, separation-axioms

Let $X$ be a topological space. Show that if every filter $F$ on $X$ converges to at most one point, then $X$ is Hausdorff.

I want to argue by contrapositive. Suppose there exists a pair of points $x$ and $y$ such that every pair of their neighborhoods intersect. Then I want to construct a filter that consists of all their neighborhoods and hence converges to both $x$ and $y$. I haven't been able to construct such a filter. Is this the correct way to proceed or are there any better methods?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The contrapositive is the right idea. The neighbourhood filters are key:

If $x$ and $y$ are such points let $\mathcal{B}=\{U \cap V: U, V \text{ open }, x \in U, y \in V\}$, which by assumption only consists of non-empty sets.

$\mathcal{B}$ forms a filter base in $X$ so it generates a filter $\mathcal{F} = \{A: \exists B \in \mathcal{B}: B \subseteq A\}$ on $X$ such that $\mathcal{F} \to x$ and $\mathcal{F} \to y$. This is trivial, as all neighbourhoods of $x$ and $y$ will be in $\mathcal{F}$.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but isn't filter also closed under intersection? In that case, $\mathcal{F}$ should also include all finite intersections of the elements in $\mathcal{B}$. How do we ensure that all such $U \cap V$ also intersect?

Comment: @Bunbury $\mathcal{B}$ is a filter base because open sets are closed under finite  intersections, check the definitions !

Comment: @Bunbury and because of that $\mathcal{F}$ is closed under finite intersections too.

Comment: I understand that $\varnothing \notin \mathcal{F}$, which means that for all $A,B \in \mathcal{B}$, $A\cap B \neq \varnothing$. What could guarantee such a condition?

Comment: @Bunbury Because we assumed (to get a contradiction) that all neighbourhoods of $x$ and $y$ intersect. So we never get the empty set. As you did in the question. My answer continues that idea.

Comment: Yes, I understand that all neighborhoods of $x$ and $y$ intersect. But we are trying to generate a filter from these intersections, so what guarantees such the intersections also intersect? i.e. if $A$ and $B$ are neighborhoods of $x$ and $C$ the neighborhood of $y$, isn't it possible that $(A\cap C)\cap (B\cap C)$ is empty?

Comment: @Bunbury If $U_1, U_2$ are neighbourhoods of $x$ and $V_1,V_2$ are neighbourhoods of $y$, then $U_1 \cap U_2$ is a neighbourhood of $x$ too and $V_1 \cap V_2$ too for $y$ and $(U_1 \cap V_1) \cap (U_2 \cap V_2)= (U_1 \cap U_2) \cap (V_1 \cap V_2)$ is of the same form so in $\mathcal{B}$ too. In particular non-empty. Intersections are associative and commutative.

Comment: Ahh yes! How did I miss that! Thank you so much!

Comment: @Bunbury We combine two (neighbourhood) filters to a common superfilter because they are "always intersecting". That's really all that's really happening.